# Python: Save dataframe to excel (win32.com)

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, win32com

I have a code that downloads data from yahoo finance to df for list of stocks. Than I create new spreadsheet for each stock. But I cannot manage to copy data from df to this spreadsheet.

```
n=number_of_stocks
m = 0
while n > 0:
    x = Input_Stock_Names[m]
    m+=1
    n-=1
    df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(x,starting_date,ending_date)
    df = df.reset_index()
    
    ExcelWrksht = ExcelWrkbook.Worksheets.Add()
    ExcelWrksht.Name = x
    ExcelWrksht = ExcelWrkbook.Worksheets(x)
```

Also excel file is open while code is running.

Comment: Is there any error message or what do you need help with? To help you solve your problem I would need to know more about the stock data if there are something creating trouble there or if it's somewhere else.

Comment: What does the data look like in the DataFrame? Are you just trying to get the data into a spreadsheet, or does the spreadsheet do something else as well? Does the spreadsheet already contain data?

Comment: @DS_London What does the data look like in the DataFrame? - class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'; 7 columns (1-st datetime64[ns], other float64 ) number off rows can vary.  I'm just trying  to add data on to new, empty spreadsheet.

Comment: If all you want to do is to write a DataFrame to a new Excel file, then `win32com` is overkill. Rather use the support for Excel files already in pandas, via the ExcelWriter class: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html This just writes a .xlsx file in the Excel format, and does not need to have the Excel application running, so will be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

If the task is to simply store downloaded data, then using `win32com` is over-engineering. Simply use the facilities within `pandas` to write to the Excel file in the `.xlsx` format:

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from datetime import date,timedelta

#90 days of history from today
end_date = date.today()
start_date = end_date - timedelta(days=90)

Input_Stock_Names = ['AAPL','TSLA','MSFT']

with pd.ExcelWriter('c:\\somepath\\stocks.xlsx',mode='w') as ew:
    for stock in Input_Stock_Names:
        df = yf.download(stock,start=start_date,end=end_date)
        df.to_excel(ew,stock)
```

This will create a new Excel file, with one sheet for each stock.

`win32com` allows you to 'drive' Excel, and do pretty much everything you would do if you had the Excel application open. However, it is relatively slow: the Excel application has to be started (and closed) and all the data and commands have to cross the 'process boundary' from one process (python) to the other (Excel).

Using `ExcelWriter` you simply write data to a file in the `.xlsx` format, so that Excel can read it later. If all you want to do is store data this is very much more efficient than using `win32com`.